# apache2 fails to execute php code with $_FILE, it execute the code if $_FILE is not in the php code

Tags: php, ubuntu, apache2

I have installed apache2 Apache/2.4.29 (Ubuntu) on my Ubuntu 18.4. Also installed php 7.2. The apache server execute the php code fine if it does not contain a call to $_FILE.

If I add $_FILE to the code, then it fails to execute the php code and it only gives a white page. Something wrong with loading $_FILE, please help!!

Comment: Please add your code to the question.

Comment: A white screen is usually related to a 500 Internal Server Error. Check your server error logs to find out what's going wrong.

Comment: are you using the variable $_FILE or $_FILES?

Comment: I am using $_FILES  like this:

Comment: $docfile = $_FILES['upload_file']['tmp_name'][0] ;

Comment: folks; I still have same issue ... please help if you can.

Comment: Please [edit] your questions instead of adding comments. Not all comments may be shown initially, and you cannot format code in comments as in questions. Make it easy for people to help you. Add your code as a [mcve]. You may want to read [ask].

Answer (score 0):

the global variable is called $_FILES for accessing files submitted through forms.